# JADE (Java) - Changing Agent Container

Tags: java, containers, agents, agents-jade

Is there a way to reassign agents to a different container or will I have to create a new container and then create all new instances of the agents within the new container?

I have done a lot of searching and can't seem to find anything on container reassignment.

Thanks in advance for any info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey I think the code you need is

```
myAgent.doMove( dest );
```

with dest being the location name of the new container as registered with the main container.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why I couldn't find that myself!